# Getting the post title in index php in a while loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="boxes-third boxes-first">       
      <div class="latestthree">
        <div class="title">
           <?php get_the_title($id); ?> // I am trying to get the post title here but doesn't work
            <span class="titlearrow"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="latestthreeimage">
    <a rel="prettyPhoto" title="<?php get_the_title($id); ?>"> /same here
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,133)); ?>
    </a></div>
            <div class="text">
             Here i would like to get the excerpt of the post that is no longer than 25 words
             <span class="textarrow"></span>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am trying to do the above mentioned, but did not worked and on the last one did not find related info. I am using wp 3.7.1. Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have used `get_the_title()` which does not print. To print out the title, add an extra `echo`:

```
 <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

Or you can use `the_title()`, which also prints:

```
<?php the_title();?>
```

Comment: You can use `the_excerpt();` for excerpt.

Comment: and how do i limit it to get only 25 words?

Comment: you need to add action into your theme's functions.php file and place below code:
add_action('the_excerpt','limit_the_content');
function limit_the_content($content){
  $word_limit =25;
  $words = explode(' ', $content);
  return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));
}

Answer (score 1):

Try just using,

```
the_title();
```

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title).